# Is the co-skewness matrix a rank-3 tensor?

Tags: matrices, tensors, matrix-rank, tensor-rank

Variance and skewness are the 2nd and 3rd statistical moments of a random variable's distribution. Unlike the variance-covariance matrix, which is shaped $p\times p$, the **skewness-coskewness matrix** is shaped $p\times p^2$. Does this make it a rank 3 tensor?

For bivariate data, $p=2$, the co-skewness matrix (flattened tensor?) looks like
$$S = 
\begin{pmatrix}
s_{1,1,1} & s_{1,1,2} & s_{2,1,1} & s_{2,1,2} \\
s_{1,2,1} & s_{1,2,2} & s_{2,2,1} & s_{2,2,2} \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Which of the elements are skewness elements, rather than co-skewness elements?

And how can this matrix be displayed as a tensor?